# How is __eq__ handled in Python and in what order?

Tags: python, comparison, user-defined

Since Python does not provide left/right versions of its comparison operators, how does it decide which function to call?

```
class A(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print "A __eq__ called"
        return self.value == other
class B(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print "B __eq__ called"
        return self.value == other

>>> a = A()
>>> a.value = 3
>>> b = B()
>>> b.value = 4
>>> a == b
"A __eq__ called"
"B __eq__ called"
False
```

This seems to call both `__eq__` functions.

I am looking for the official decision tree.

Comment: @呂殿下-Luidenka Please don't edit questions to update python code from 2 to 3 unless the question tagged and clearly about python 3. (See this meta post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421314/6689725)

Answer (score 168, accepted):

The `a == b` expression invokes `A.__eq__`, since it exists.  Its code includes `self.value == other`.  Since int's don't know how to compare themselves to B's, Python tries invoking `B.__eq__` to see if it knows how to compare itself to an int.

If you amend your code to show what values are being compared:

```
class A(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print("A __eq__ called: %r == %r ?" % (self, other))
        return self.value == other
class B(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print("B __eq__ called: %r == %r ?" % (self, other))
        return self.value == other

a = A()
a.value = 3
b = B()
b.value = 4
a == b
```

it will print:

```
A __eq__ called: <__main__.A object at 0x013BA070> == <__main__.B object at 0x013BA090> ?
B __eq__ called: <__main__.B object at 0x013BA090> == 3 ?
```

Comment: Also relevant in Python3 to ones who wondered.

Answer (score 74):

When Python2.x sees `a == b`, it tries the following.

- If `type(b)` is a new-style class, and `type(b)` is a subclass of `type(a)`, and `type(b)` has overridden `__eq__`, then the result is `b.__eq__(a)`.
- If `type(a)` has overridden `__eq__` (that is, `type(a).__eq__` isn't `object.__eq__`), then the result is `a.__eq__(b)`.
- If `type(b)` has overridden `__eq__`, then the result is `b.__eq__(a)`.
- If none of the above are the case, Python repeats the process looking for `__cmp__`. If it exists, the objects are equal iff it returns `zero`.
- As a final fallback, Python calls `object.__eq__(a, b)`, which is `True` iff `a` and `b` are the same object.

If any of the special methods return `NotImplemented`, Python acts as though the method didn't exist.

Note that last step carefully: if neither `a` nor `b` overloads `==`, then `a == b` is the same as `a is b`.

---

From https://eev.ee/blog/2012/03/24/python-faq-equality/

Comment: Uhh it seems the python 3 docs were incorrect. See http://bugs.python.org/issue4395 and the patch for clarification. TLDR: subclass still compared first, even if it's on the rhs.

Comment: Hi kev, nice post.  Could you explain where the first bullet point is documented and why it's designed like that?

Comment: Yep where is this documented for python 2 ? Is it a PEP ?

Comment: base on this answer and accompanied comments , this just left me more confused than before.

Comment: and btw, is define a bound method `__eq__`  on just the instance of some type  not enough for == to be overriden?

Comment: Thought why is this search for `__eq__` not recursive scaling up the class hierarchy?

Answer (score 53):

### Python 3 Changes/Updates for this algorithm

> ### How is `__eq__` handled in Python and in what order?
>
> ```
> a == b
> ```

It is generally understood, but not always the case, that `a == b` invokes `a.__eq__(b)`, or `type(a).__eq__(a, b)`.

Explicitly, the order of evaluation is:

1. if `b`'s type is a strict subclass (not the same type) of `a`'s type and has an `__eq__`, call it and return the value if the comparison is implemented,
2. else, if `a` has `__eq__`, call it and return it if the comparison is implemented,
3. else, see if we didn't call b's `__eq__` and it has it, then call and return it if the comparison is implemented,
4. else, finally, do the comparison for identity, the same comparison as `is`.

We know if a comparison isn't implemented if the method returns `NotImplemented`.

(In Python 2, there was a `__cmp__` method that was looked for, but it was deprecated and removed in Python 3.)

Let's test the first check's behavior for ourselves by letting B subclass A, which shows that the accepted answer is wrong on this count:

```py
class A:
    value = 3
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print('A __eq__ called')
        return self.value == other.value

class B(A):
    value = 4
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print('B __eq__ called')
        return self.value == other.value

a, b = A(), B()
a == b
```

which only prints `B __eq__ called` before returning `False`.

Note that I also correct a small error in the question where `self.value` is compared to `other` instead of `other.value` - in this comparison, we get two objects (`self` and `other`), usually of the same type since we are doing no type-checking here (but they can be of different types), and we need to know if they are equal. Our measure of whether or not they are equal is to check the `value` attribute, which must be done on both objects.

### How do we know this full algorithm?

The other answers here seem incomplete and out of date, so I'm going to update the information *and* show you how how you could look this up for yourself.

This is handled at the C level.

We need to look at two different bits of code here - the default `__eq__` for objects of class `object`, and the code that looks up and calls the `__eq__` method regardless of whether it uses the default `__eq__` or a custom one.

#### Default `__eq__`

Looking `__eq__` up in the [relevant C api docs](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html) shows us that `__eq__` is handled by [`tp_richcompare`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_richcompare) - which in the `"object"` type definition in [`cpython/Objects/typeobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c) is defined in `object_richcompare` for `case Py_EQ:`.

```
    case Py_EQ:
        /* Return NotImplemented instead of False, so if two
           objects are compared, both get a chance at the
           comparison.  See issue #1393. */
        res = (self == other) ? Py_True : Py_NotImplemented;
        Py_INCREF(res);
        break;
```

So here, if `self == other` we return `True`, else we return the `NotImplemented` object. This is the default behavior for any subclass of object that does not implement its own `__eq__` method.

#### How `__eq__` gets called

Then we find the C API docs, the [PyObject_RichCompare](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompare) function, which calls `do_richcompare`.

Then we see that the `tp_richcompare` function, created for the `"object"` C definition is called by `do_richcompare`, so let's look at that a little more closely.

The first check in this function is for the conditions the objects being compared:

- are *not* the same type, but
- the second's type is a subclass of the first's type, and
- the second's type has an `__eq__` method,

then call the other's method with the arguments swapped, returning the value if implemented. If that method isn't implemented, we continue...

```
    if (!Py_IS_TYPE(v, Py_TYPE(w)) &&
        PyType_IsSubtype(Py_TYPE(w), Py_TYPE(v)) &&
        (f = Py_TYPE(w)->tp_richcompare) != NULL) {
        checked_reverse_op = 1;
        res = (*f)(w, v, _Py_SwappedOp[op]);
        if (res != Py_NotImplemented)
            return res;
        Py_DECREF(res);
```

Next we see if we can lookup the `__eq__` method from the first type and call it.
As long as the result is not NotImplemented, that is, it is implemented, we return it.

```
    if ((f = Py_TYPE(v)->tp_richcompare) != NULL) {
        res = (*f)(v, w, op);
        if (res != Py_NotImplemented)
            return res;
        Py_DECREF(res);
```

Else if we didn't try the other type's method and it's there, we then try it, and if the comparison is implemented, we return it.

```
    if (!checked_reverse_op && (f = Py_TYPE(w)->tp_richcompare) != NULL) {
        res = (*f)(w, v, _Py_SwappedOp[op]);
        if (res != Py_NotImplemented)
            return res;
        Py_DECREF(res);
    }
```

Finally, we get a fallback in case it isn't implemented for either one's type.

The fallback checks for the identity of the object, that is, whether it is the same object at the same place in memory - this is the same check as for `self is other`:

```
    /* If neither object implements it, provide a sensible default
       for == and !=, but raise an exception for ordering. */
    switch (op) {
    case Py_EQ:
        res = (v == w) ? Py_True : Py_False;
        break;
```

### Conclusion

In a comparison, we respect the subclass implementation of comparison first.

Then we attempt the comparison with the first object's implementation, then with the second's if it wasn't called.

Finally we use a test for identity for comparison for equality.

Comment: Thank you for providing an update for Python3 in 2020. Maybe worthwhile mentioning that math operators have different handlers for left/right and both get tried, e.g. a=A(), a+1 calls a.__add__ and 1+a tries A.__radd__ if int add cannot handle A. Any thoughts on how a failing 1+a gets caught, leading to A.__radd__?

Comment: *"accepted answer is wrong on this count"* But they have `self.value == other` unlike your post.

Comment: that is an additional error on the part of the asker that I tacitly corrected, but I have now made it explicit with a note explaining what I am doing...

Comment: Great detailed answer. Just for records, here is the relevant section from [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__): *If the operands are of different types, and right operand’s type is a direct or indirect subclass of the left operand’s type, the reflected method of the right operand has priority, otherwise the left operand’s method has priority. Virtual subclassing is not considered.*