# How int() object uses "==" operator without __eq__() method in python2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-internals

Recently I read the "Fluent python" and understood how `==` operator works with python objects, using `__eq__()` method. But how it works with `int` instances in python2?

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 1
>>> a == b
True
>>> a.__eq__(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__eq__'
```

in python3 all `a.__eq__(b)` returns `True`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588776/how-is-eq-handled-in-python-and-in-what-order look at a few answers here, i think they explain it well

Comment: Wild guess, but `from operator import eq; eq(2,2)` does work in Python2. Either that or using `__cmp__`

Comment: `a.__cmp__` exists, which might be what Python 2 is using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python [prefers to use rich comparison functions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ge__) (`__eq__`, `__lt__`, `__ne__`, etc.), but if those don't exist, it falls back to using a single comparison function (`__cmp__`, removed in Python 3):

> These are the so-called “rich comparison” methods, and are called for comparison operators in preference to `__cmp__()` below.

The [Python 2 integer type](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/intobject.c#L1414-L1455) doesn't implement a rich comparison function:

```
PyTypeObject PyInt_Type = {
    ...
    (cmpfunc)int_compare,                       /* tp_compare */
    ...
    0,                                          /* tp_richcompare */
```

In Python 3, the [integer type](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/intobject.c#L1414-L1455) (now a long) implements only a rich comparison function, since Python 3 dropped support for `__cmp__`:

```
PyTypeObject PyLong_Type = {
    ...
    long_richcompare,                           /* tp_richcompare */
```

This is why `(123).__eq__` doesn't exist. Instead, Python 2 falls back to `(123).__cmp__` when testing the equality of two integers:

```
>>> (1).__eq__(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__eq__'
>>> (1).__cmp__(2)
-1
```

Answer (score 6):

In Python 2, the `int` object uses the `__cmp__()` method instead of the rich methods like `__eq__()`, `__lt__()`, `__gt__()`, and others.

Comment: How do you know this? Do you have a reference in the documentation, or ... ?

Comment: You can check this by running `dir(int_instance)` in Python; there's no `__eq__` method available. You can read more about `__cmp__()` versus the rich operators [here.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer.

```
import sys
SPECIAL_OPNAMES = \
    { '__eq__': (lambda *args, **kwargs: not cmp(*args, **kwargs)) \
    , '__ne__': (lambda *args, **kwargs: cmp(*args, **kwargs)) \
    , '__lt__': (lambda *args, **kwargs: cmp(*args, **kwargs) < 0) \
    , '__ge__': (lambda *args, **kwargs: cmp(*args, **kwargs) >= 0) \
    , '__gt__': (lambda *args, **kwargs: cmp(*args, **kwargs) > 0) \
    , '__le__': (lambda *args, **kwargs: cmp(*args, **kwargs) <= 0) \
    } if sys.version_info.major == 2 else \
    {}
```

Working example:

```
>>> item = 1
>>> opname = '__eq__'
>>> t = type(item)
>>> op = SPECIAL_OPNAMES[opname] if opname in SPECIAL_OPNAMES else getattr(t, opname)
>>> op(item, 1)
True
```