# Why is `int.__eq__(other)` a working comparison?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following code works with Python 2.7:

```
>>> class Derived(int):
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return int.__eq__(other)
...
>>> Derived(12) == 12.0
True
>>> Derived(12) == 13
False
```

I do not understand, why it works, given that the `self` attribute is not explicitly given to `int.__eq__()` method call.

[EDIT]

Answers so far suggested, that it is about returning `NotImplemented` by `self.__eq__(other)` and thus calling `other.__eq__(self)`. Then `Derived(12) == Derived(12)` I expect to be an infinitive recursion, which is not the case:

```
>>> Derived(12) == Derived(12)
True
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works because `int.__eq__(<something>)` returns `NotImplemented` and when that happens it results in a call to `other.__eq__(self)` and that's what is returning `True` and `False` here.

**Demo:**

```
class Derived(int):
     def __eq__(self, other):
         print self, other
         print int.__eq__(other)
         print other.__eq__(self)
         return int.__eq__(other)

>>> Derived(12) == 12.0
12 12.0
NotImplemented
True
True
>>> Derived(12) == 13.0
12 13.0
NotImplemented
False
False
```

From [`NotImplemented`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented)
's docs:

> Special value which should be returned by the binary special methods
>   (e.g. `__eq__()`, `__lt__()`, `__add__()`, `__rsub__()`, etc.) to
>   indicate that the operation is not implemented with respect to the
>   other type; may be returned by the in-place binary special methods
>   (e.g. `__imul__()`, `__iand__()`, etc.) for the same purpose. Its
>   truth value is true.
>
> Note When `NotImplemented` is returned, the interpreter will then try
>   the reflected operation on the other type, or some other fallback,
>   depending on the operator. If all attempted operations return
>   NotImplemented, the interpreter will raise an appropriate exception.

---

**What happens when both `__eq__` return `NotImplemented`?**

The behaviour is different in Python 2 and 3.

In Python 2 it falls back to `__cmp__` method first and integers have [`__cmp__` method in Python 2](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/longobject.c#l2886). It has been removed in Python 3.

As per Python 2 docs if nothing is found it ultimately falls back to identity comparison:

> If no `__cmp__()`, `__eq__()` or `__ne__()` operation is defined, class
>   instances are compared by object identity (“address”)

```
class Derived(int):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print ("Inside  __eq__")
        return NotImplemented

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        print ("Inside __cmp__ finally")
        return True

>>> Derived(12) == Derived(12)
Inside  __eq__
Inside  __eq__
Inside __cmp__ finally
False
```

Not let's define a class with no method defined:

```
class Derived(object):
    pass

>>> Derived() == Derived()  
False
>>> d = Derived()
>>> d == d  # Same objects.
True
```

Python 3 doesn't have `__cmp__` method anymore but it seems to be falling back to identity now. And it seems it is not documented either.

```
#  Python 3.5
>>> Derived() == Derived()
False
>>> d = Derived()
>>> d == d
True
```

Answer (score 1):

> When mixing float with an integer type, there's no good *uniform* approach.
>   https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/floatobject.c#L401-L417

P.S.
[How int() object using "==" operator without __eq__() method in python2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921558/how-int-object-using-operator-without-eq-method-in-python2/36922306#36922306)

Comment: Oh, come on, 12 is not even overflowing half-precision float. It converts perfectly fine to a double.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7, if you call `int.__eq__` it always returns `NotImplemented`.  Example:

```
>>> int.__eq__(12.0)
NotImplemented
```

When you use the `==` operator it will attempt to run the `__eq__` method on the left argument, and if it gets `NotImplemented` it will return the result of the `__eq__` method from the argument on the right.

In your example for `Derived(12) == 12.0`, the interpreter first tries `Derived(12).__eq__(12.0)`, and gets `NotImplemented`.  It then runs the `__eq__` method on the `float` number `12.0` and gets `True`.

In the case of your `Derived(12) == Derived(12)` example, what's likely happening is that since both objects return `NotImplemented` for their `__eq__` methods, and since `Derived` inherits from `int`, the interpreter falls back to using the `cmp` builtin behavior for `int` (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36922306/7007605), which is linked-to in another answer to your question).

Here's an example that illustrates your case:

```
class Derived(int):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print 'Doing eq'
        return NotImplemented
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        print 'doing cmp'
        return 0  # contrived example - don't do this

>>> Derived(12) == Derived(12)
doing eq
doing eq
doing cmp
True
```

Comment: Edited to take into account all args for `int.__eq__`

Comment: Updated the question to include `Derived(12) == Derived(12)` case