# What is "list.__eq__(self, other)" supposed to do?

Tags: python

I'm a python newbie and yesterday I had to dive into the source code of graphite-web open source project. But my question is not specifically about graphite.

I found this function:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
  if not isinstance(other, TimeSeries):
    return False

  if hasattr(self, 'color'):
    if not hasattr(other, 'color') or (self.color != other.color):
      return False
  elif hasattr(other, 'color'):
    return False

  return ((self.name, self.start, self.end, self.step, self.consolidationFunc, self.valuesPerPoint, self.options, self.xFilesFactor) ==
  (other.name, other.start, other.end, other.step, other.consolidationFunc, other.valuesPerPoint, other.options, other.xFilesFactor)) and list.__eq__(self, other)
```

I understand what this method is supposed to do (I come from the java world, and this is quite familiar). My interrogation is about this sample, at the end :

```
list.__eq__(self, other)
```

Why is it here and what is this supposed to do ?

Many thanks :)

Comment: you can find related info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588776/how-is-eq-handled-in-python-and-in-what-order)

Comment: Without more context, one cannot say *why* it is there, but simply put, it is calling the `list.__eq__` method with the arguments `self` and `other`... does this class inherit from `list`?

Comment: This is from actual code of list class `""" x.__eq__(other) <==> x==other """`. General purpose is to check equality but can be for doing other task in your code

Comment: `__eq__` method of list class is used to check if two lists are equal. `list.__eq__([1,2,3],[1,2,3])` produce `True` and `list.__eq__([1,2,3],[1,2,3,4])` produce `False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class in question seems to be a sub-class of `list`, with some additional attributes like `name`, `start`, etc., and by calling `list.__eq__(self, other)`, you explicitly call the `__eq__` method of `list` (instead of the one defined in the subclass) to compare the two objects. This will likely compare the *content* of the two lists after their other attributes have been checked for equality.

Usually, `cls.method(obj, *args)` is equivalent to `obj.method(*args)`, *if* `obj` is an instance of `cls`, but in this case, just calling `self.__eq__(other)` (or `self == other`) would call the same `__eq__` method again, resulting in an infinite recursion.

Since you said that you are coming from Java: Provided that this class *is* a subclass from `list`, calling `list.__eq__(self, other)` is similar to calling `super.equals(other)`.