# How to get the Enum value by default when used in a comparison?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I have created a Enum class as shown:

```py
class MsgType(Enum):
    # ADMINISTRATIVE MESSAGE
    HEARTBEAT = "0"
    LOGON = "A"
    LOGOUT = "5"
    REJECT_SESSION_LEVEL = "3"
    RESEND_REQUEST = "2"
    SEQUENCE_RESET = "4"
    SESSION_REJECT = "3"
    TEST_REQUEST = "1"
```

I want to use this class for comparison with a string that I get after reading a message. I am comparing the values as shown. The value in `msg_type` is a of type `str`.

```py
def read_admin_msg(message):
    msg_type = read_header(message)
    if msg_type == ct.MsgType.HEARTBEAT:
        print(msg_type)
    elif msg_type == ct.MsgType.LOGON:
        print(msg_type)
    elif msg_type == ct.MsgType.LOGOUT:
        print(msg_type)
    elif msg_type == ct.MsgType.REJECT_SESSION_LEVEL:
        print(msg_type)
    elif msg_type == ct.MsgType.RESEND_REQUEST:
        print(msg_type)
    elif msg_type == ct.MsgType.SEQUENCE_RESET:
        print(msg_type)
    elif msg_type == ct.MsgType.SESSION_REJECT:
        print(msg_type)
    elif msg_type == ct.MsgType.TEST_REQUEST:
        print(msg_type)
    else:
        print("Not found")
        print(msg_type)
```

My expectation is that for `msg_type = "A"` the statement `msg_type == ct.MsgType.LOGON` should be `True` but instead `else` statement is executed.

If I write `ct.MsgType.LOGON.value` then I get the desired result. But I want this behavior to be default for the class. Which method should I override or should I try a different approach?

Comment: What does read_header returns?

Comment: It returns a `str` and it's value is one of the values in `MsgType()` class

Comment: I actually would like to return enum value when i call it like this `ct.MsgType.LOGON` but there is no solution to that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`msg_type = "A"` is the *value* of the Enum. You need to change one side of your equal comparisons. Either:

```
elif msg_type == MsgType.LOGON.value:
    print(msg_type)
```

or this:

```
# This one is probably preferred
elif MsgType(msg_type) == MsgType.LOGON:
    print(msg_type)
```

EDIT: I see your statement about using `.value` now. That's just how these enums work...if you want to override the `__eq__` on your `MsgType` class, you can. But you'd be breaking the default equality comparison for `Enums` in the process, and you'd have to have special type checking in there for checking if your left/right side is a string/Enum/etc. I'd just make your `read_header` function return an instance of the Enum, and not the string value.

Comment: In the second case, probably better to do it when getting the value: `msg_type = ct.MsgType(read_header(message))`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Heh, yep, I was just putting that into my edit I just posted.

Answer (score 3):

The key question here is what should happen if `msg_type` is invalid.  For example, either because of a bug or corruption `msg_type == 'z'`.

If an exception is appropriate then the easiest way to get it is with

```
msg_type = MsgType(msg_type)
```

which will generate a `ValueError` for illegal values, and you can either deal with it immediately:

```
try:
    msg_type = MsgType(msg_type)
    # your if...elif...else here
except ValueError:
    # handle problem here
```

or let it bubble up to a higher function.

If you don't want/need exceptions, then another way around around having to compare with `MsgType.LOGON.value` is to make the `MsgType` `Enum` derive from `str` as well:

```
class MsgType(str, Enum):
    # definitions here
```

Then in your code you can say:

```
if msg_type == 'A':
    # stuff
```

without converting `msg_type` to `MsgType`.

My preference is the first method (not mixing in `str`, and doing the conversion) unless you are adding `Enum` to an existing code base and `LOGON`, `HEARTBEAT`, etc. are constants and already in use elsewhere.

Note that even with the second method you can still use `MsgType(msg_type)` to raise a `ValueError` exception if you need to.

Comment: I do like this solution, `class MsgType(str, Enum):`

Answer (score 1):

#### Override `__eq__` to check either `Enum` or `Enum.value`

For Enums with string values, one solution to avoid explicitly calling `Enum.value` is to override `__eq__` to check if the Enum is being compared to a string, and if not, then use the default Enum equality check.

```py
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, str):
        return self.value == other

    if isinstance(other, Enum):
        return self.value == other.value

    return False
```

Note that this works if the Enum is on the left-hand or right-hand side of the equality.

See also:

- [**How is `__eq__` handled in Python and in what order?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3588776/1164465)
- [**Elegant ways to support equivalence ("equality") in Python classes**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/390640/1164465)

#### Example

```py
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class MyEnum(Enum):
        BAR = 'bar'
        def __eq__(self, other):
            if isinstance(other, str):
                return self.value == other
            if isinstance(other, Enum):
                return self.value == other.value
            return False
   
>>> MyEnum.BAR == MyEnum.BAR
True
>>> MyEnum.BAR == 'bar'
True
>>> 'bar' == MyEnum.BAR
True
>>> MyEnum.BAR.value == 'bar'
True
>>> MyEnum.BAR == 'foo'
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also be solved by adding a `__get__` method in your enumeration.

```py
>>> from enum import Enum

>>> class MsgType(Enum):
        HEARTBEAT = "0"
        LOGON = "A"
        def __get__(self, instance, owner):
                return self.value

>>> MsgType.HEARTBEAT
'0'
>>> MsgType.LOGON == "A"
True
```

**Warning :** Using this method, `Enum.value` & `Enum.name` attributes would no longer be accessible for given class.