# How to selectively override '==' behaviour in Python?

Tags: python, overriding

Environment: Python 2.7 (It just might have something to do with this.)

First I understand the '==' is implemented as following ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588776/how-is-eq-handled-in-python-and-in-what-order)):

> 1. if
>
>    - `type(b)` is a new-style class,
>    - `type(b)` is a subclass of `type(a)`
>    - `type(b)` has overridden `__eq__`
>
> then the result is `b.__eq__(a)`
>
> 2. If
>
>    - `type(a)` has overridden `__eq__` (that is, `type(a).__eq__` isn't `object.__eq__`)
>
> then the result is `a.__eq__(b)`
>
> 3. If
>
>    - `type(b)` has overridden `__eq__`
>
> then the result is `b.__eq__(a)`.
>
> 4. If none of the above are the case, repeats the process above, but looking for `__cmp__`. If it exists, the objects are equal if it returns zero.
> 5. As a final fallback, Python calls `object.__eq__(a, b)`, which is just testing if a and b are the same object.

.

Now I want to override `__eq__` of an object, but falls back to the mechanism above when object has no custom `__eq__` defined. **How to achieve this?**

I can't just save the original `__eq__` method because '==' actually involves a complex mechanism described above.

Example Code (with target not achieved):

```
class A(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            self.___eq___
            return self.___eq___(other)
        except AttributeError:
            # trying to save default behaviour (Goal)

def custom_eq_bound_method(self, other):
    return True

# overriding __eq__
a1 = A()
a1.___eq___ = MethodType(custom_eq_bound_method, a1, A)

# not overriding __eq__
a2 = A()

# comparing a1 == a2 in business logic....
```

Comment: 1. What do you mean under "new style class"? 2. What is the difference between `b.__eq__(a)` and `a.__eq__(b)`? 3. Why to not override such as behaviour in each type. As I interpret your problem in my head .. there should not be a problem, just declare classes and override methods properly.

Comment: *Why* would you want to override `__eq__` for a single object? This sounds like a design problem.

Comment: @chepner  I have different sets of functions to tweak objects produced by same class, potentially adding attributes to them.  I want to compare objects tweaked by the same set of functions.

Comment: Then you probably want separate subclasses, rather than hacking objects of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've asked this before and had it answered, but it seems what you are looking for is to have the class to try to defer to your own alias for `__eq__` since this method cannot be overridden at the instance level.

```
from types import MethodType
class A(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            self._eq
            return self._eq(other)        # defer to _eq
        except AttributeError:
            return super().__eq__(other)  # Here is the default behaviour

def custom_eq_bound_method(self, other):
    return True

a1 = A()
a2 = A()
a3 = A()

print(a1==a2)
print(a1==a3)
print(a2==a3)

a1._eq = MethodType(custom_eq_bound_method, a1)
print('After override')

print(a1==a2)
print(a1==a3)
print(a2==a3)
```

Output:

```
False
False
False
After override
True
True
False
```

Comment: if you try your code in python2.7, you will get an error : AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__eq__' (even if substitue `super().__eq__` to `super(self.__class__).__eq__`

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm running python 3.

Comment: and btw how is using `super().__eq__` can achieve the same effect of that complex mechanism described in my question?

Comment: I don't know. I am simply following the code that you post.