# `in` operator on a list vs `or` operator with multiple conditions - python

Tags: python, if-statement

I've been using python3 a lot for a class recently and figured out that you can write

```
if x in [1,2,3]:
    print("x is 1,2 or 3")
```

instead of

```
if x == 1 or x == 2 or x ==3:
    print("x is 1,2 or 3")
```

Is this considered good or bad practice, is it "pythonic" ?

## Edit

The consensus seems to be that

```
if x in {1,2,3}: # set {}, not list []
    print("x is 1,2 or 3")
```

is more efficient, O(1) vs O(n), and therefore faster. Also, it expresses the same things less verbosely which makes it more "pythonic" as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL;DR:

Yes.

## Longer Answer:

It isn't less efficient for sure, as @Selcuk mentioned in the comments:

> The performance difference comes from implementation overheads, otherwise they are both `O(n)` while `set` operation is actually faster as it is `O(1)`.

Hearing set should confuse you, first read through everything and at the end you will see `set` membership testing, here are the timings:

```
from timeit import timeit
x = 2
print(timeit(lambda: x in [1, 2, 3], number=10000000))
print(timeit(lambda: x == 1 or x == 2 or x == 3, number=10000000))
```

Output:

```
2.9532112044043597
3.614175814476062
```

So it means, that your first solution with list membership testing is faster than multiple `or` conditions.

As @Austin mentioned, `set` membership testing is faster.

So if we check `set` membership timing, like:

```
from timeit import timeit
x = 2
print(timeit(lambda: x in {1, 2, 3}, number=10000000))
```

It will output:

```
2.7767165870317445
```

So `set` membership is the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

A slight version of first one would be more pythonic:

```
if x in {1,2,3}:
```

Always a membership check on set is of constant time, though there would be a set creation time (which in some cases can be a bottleneck).

Answer (score 1):

The in keyword has two purposes:

- The in keyword is used to check if a value is present in a sequence
  (list, range, string etc.).
- The in keyword is also used to iterate through a sequence in a for
  loop

As to my knowledge the "in" calls the [**eq**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588776/how-is-eq-handled-in-python-and-in-what-order) method to check if the given entry matches the current list in this case hence forth both achieve the same thing.
As to answer the question if this is "pythonic", then yes the in function saves several lines of iteration that were previously required to iterate and compare the list or any other data structure.

Here is the time [complexity documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for future reference , it also explains the time complexity of the in keyword which is O(n) on average