# Get __repr__ to return string that has same value when passed to eval?

Tags: python, class, repr

I don't fully understand what is going on here. Why does the returned string from repr evaluate to False? If anyone can expand on what I'm not understanding here, that would be really appreciated.

```
class Bag(object):
    def __init__(self, iter_vals = []):
        self.iter_vals = iter_vals
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Bag({str(self.iter_vals)})"
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = Bag(['d','a','b','d','c','b','d'])
    print(eval(repr(b)) == b)

>>> False
```

Comment: Hmm, I’d guess because you need to implement `__eq__` on the class?

Comment: Unless you implement `eq` or this is some sort of @DataClass, equality on objects is defined as being the same object.

Comment: To clarify, since `__eq__` isn't implemented, Python falls back to using `id`, which you can see will not evaluate to `True` if you check `id(b)` and `id(eval(repr(b)))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is \_\_eq\_\_ handled in Python and in what order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588776/how-is-eq-handled-in-python-and-in-what-order)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to define an `__eq__` method to define *how* a `Bag` is equal to another `Bag`:

```py
class Bag(object):
    def __init__(self, iter_vals = []):
        self.iter_vals = iter_vals
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Bag({str(self.iter_vals)})"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other,Bag):
            raise TypeError('not a Bag')
        return self.iter_vals == other.iter_vals
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = Bag(['d','a','b','d','c','b','d'])
    print(eval(repr(b)) == b)  # True
```